# Two intact groups and independent sample t-test

Tags: statistical-significance, pre-post-comparison, control-group

The purpose of my research study is to measure the effect of project-oriented instruction approach on students' cultural awareness and their attitude towards the learning of foreign cultures. My two intact groups, randomly assigned to experimental and control groups, are essentially the same on the pretest and neither group has been previously exposed to the treatment planned for it.

Can I use a t-test rather than the analysis of covariance approach although the assumption of independence is violated?

Comment: Why do you think you lack independence?

Comment: Some questions: What is the meaning of 'intact' in 'intact group"? Can you quantify 'essentially' in 'essentially the same on ... pretest'? 'Use a t test' on what data? Will both groups take a post-test that is thought to assess the same attitudes as the pre-test?

Comment: Dave - lacks independence as the research participants are not randomly assigned to the two groups by the researcher. Put differently, the groups are artificial.  Applying independent sample t-test requires some assumptions.

Comment: BruceET : I couldn't form two groups randomly because of the research setting constraints, so I had to use two existing groups already formed by the administration based on grades and gender. Despite this, we cannot consider them equivalent as they are not randomly assigned. I assigned two existing groups to a control group and an experimental group randomly. Prior the treatment, the two groups were pretested, administered a treatment and posttested. Pretest scores show that there is no statistical difference in their means. Can I use independent sample t-test to compare their posttest means?